# CodeNameOne Uploading Image to servlet with StateMachine Problems

Tags: java, servlets, codenameone

I started using CodeNameOne a week ago so am pretty green with this and these types of frameworks and I'm trying to upload images to a servlet using the demo UploadServlet, I've got this working OK with the PhotoShare Demo although I am finding it hard to upload with an app I built with the CodeNameOne GUI Designer and StateMachine class.

Can anyone point me into what I need to do to the code here, doesn't seem to matter if I queue and wait or not the postResponse seems to fire straight away.

Thanks in advance

Error:

```
Done probably too early
[EDT] 0:0:0,0 - Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException - null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at userclasses.StateMachine$2.postResponse(StateMachine.java:756)
    at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest$1.run(ConnectionRequest.java:459)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1149)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.edtLoopImpl(Display.java:1093)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1203)
    at com.codename1.ui.Display.invokeAndBlock(Display.java:1241)
    at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager.addToQueueAndWait(NetworkManager.java:596)
    at userclasses.StateMachine.onRecordStyle_CaptureImagesAction(StateMachine.java:772)
    at generated.StateMachineBase.handleComponentAction(StateMachineBase.java:1478)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.UIBuilder$FormListener.actionPerformed(UIBuilder.java:2831)
    at com.codename1.ui.util.EventDispatcher.fireActionEvent(EventDispatcher.java:345)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.fireActionEvent(Button.java:397)
    at com.codename1.ui.Button.released(Button.java:428)
```

Code:

```
// Record Style Form - Capture Images Button -- WIP
@Override
protected void onRecordStyle_CaptureImagesAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {

    // Clear out the existing imageList 
    //imageList = null;

    // Loop over the number of photos allowed for each record
    for (int i=0; i < maxImageUploads; i++) {

        // Capture and add
        String picture = Capture.capturePhoto(1024, -1);

        System.out.println(picture);

        if (picture != null) {

            MultipartRequest mp = new MultipartRequest() {
                private long key;

                @Override
                protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                    DataInputStream di = new DataInputStream(input);
                    System.out.println("Done, probably too early!! :(");
                    key = di.readLong();
                }

                @Override
                protected void postResponse() {
                    imageList.addImageId(key);                    
                }

            };

            try {
                String uuid = WebServiceProxy.getUUID();
                mp.setUrl(apiURL + "/upload");
                mp.addData(uuid + ".jpg", picture, "image/jpeg");
                mp.addArgument("p", uuid + ":" + Preferences.get("clientUUID", "") + ":" + Preferences.get("companyUUID", ""));
                //mp.addArgument("UUID", uuid);
                //mp.addArgument("Client", Preferences.get("clientUUID", ""));
                //mp.addArgument("Company", Preferences.get("companyUUID", ""));
                InfiniteProgress prog = new InfiniteProgress();
                Dialog dlg = prog.showInifiniteBlocking();
                mp.setDisposeOnCompletion(dlg);
                NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(mp);

                System.out.println("Added to queue");

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }                   

        }
        // After capture ask to take another other than the last time
        if ( i < maxImageUploads - 1) {
            if (!Dialog.show("QR", "Capture image #" + (i + 2) + " ?" , "OK", "Finished")) {
                // Break out of loop if user decides 
                i = maxImageUploads;    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `imageList` variable is null and you add to it in `postResponse`.

Its pretty clear from the stack trace.

FYI for future reference it is usually helpful to annotate the line numbers from the code matching the line numbers from the stack trace. E.g. say something like:

> Line 756 is:

```
imageList.addImageId(key);
```

Comment: Thanks for both the hint on the variable and tip on reporting issues, this is my first post, thanks for your patience :). I see I had not instantiated the object for some reason I thought the object was static and I had done this earlier. I'm new to async and gwt etc. and your videos and samples are invaluable when trying to learn all this stuff. I'll update once I've got it running. Thanks again.

Comment: Just following up on this, once I realized there was a similar object on the server side which I had instantiated but not the one on the client side I got it working.

Comment: Great, FYI when an answer is correct on SO you should click the checkbox next to it in order to accept it (and an upvote is also nice) the value of both indicates that the answer is correct and helpful. This gives you points which add up to more privileges on the site.